# How to use div in phonegap blackberry os5?

Tags: html, blackberry, cordova

I try to use div in blackberry os 5 and 7 but i cant get the proper result. please guide me..
or give a proper method of designing. i need scrollable div without wrapping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format to use div in phonegap blackberry os5

```
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Auth Demo</h1>
   </div>

    <div data-role="content">    

        <form id="loginForm">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
           <label for="username">Username:</label>
           <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
           <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" />
       </div>

       <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton">
        </form>

    </div>
 <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>&copy; Camden Enterprises</h4>
   </div>

</div>
```